# How to change display to responsive and not reload page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website has 2 displays: PC view and Mobile view. I want when I change browser view to responsive, my web is change the display to mobile view but not reload the window. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, so when you switch mode from web to mobile in dev tools ? what you want to achieve ?

Comment: This is a very opinion-oriented question. There's CSS with the use of media queries to change the CSS rules applied based on screen size. There are frameworks that do this for you, each with their own design decisions. There's no one-size-fits-all answer to this. Do some research into responsive design/frameworks and choose what works best for you.

Comment: Try media queries where you can specify the styles for the view port size, it would be automatically applied without reloading.

Comment: `Media Query` is the most common way to achieve your target.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes, when I switch mode from web to mobile in dev tools.

Comment: So let me explain what i understood, so you will click on toggle device bar option in dev tools, assume your page has some form and when it is in web view you have typed Art and when you click on the device bar option tool changed to responsive you need to clear the values in the input form basically how the page loads initial look ? is that what you are looking for

Comment: try this one and let me know whether it worked for you, window.onresize = () => { window.location.reload()}

Comment: In a nutshell, you like to reload the windows? then @DILEEPTHOMAS has proper solution.

Comment: @Artemis Kindly check the answer, please vote and accept if it has helped in the solution !!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed further on the comments,

So on clicking of toggle device bar option in dev tools, assume your page has some form and when it is in web view you have typed `Art` some string in the input field  and when you click on the device bar option tool changed to responsive you need to clear the values in the input form basically how the page loads initial look.

So you can use resize event on the window object and trigger a reload whenever resize happens

**ES-6 latest**

```
window.onresize = () => { window.location.reload()}
```

**Older**

```
window.onresize = function(){ window.location.reload()}
```

If you don't want to reload the page, you can use [responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp), its basically done in css part.

In mobile responsiveness you will adding a width like for example, till 1024 which is desktop you can have this css

If it is below 720 like tablet view need to use this css, like wise how it works.

You can read more on the above link.